# Is there a version of buddypress in arabic?

Tags: php, wordpress, multilingual, buddypress

I downloaded and installed the Wordpress arabic version. I would also like to install the arabic version for buddypress. Does such translation exist? If it doesn't, where can I submit translations?

Answer (score 2):

There is an Arabic translation according to [GlotPress](http://translate.wordpress.org/projects/buddypress/dev). This language is very incomplete at the moment, and you can help by following the instructions on the [getting started](http://translate.wordpress.org/getting-started) section.

Good luck. BuddyPress has a very large POT file. Translating it is not a trivial job.